# Div height 100% following two float divs inside

Tags: html, css, division

I want to arrange two divs horizontally inside a div. The two divs height flexible, because there is a table in it. A table can be filtered so the height sometime must be changed. I want the outside div can dynamically following two divs inside. I use height 100% for outside div to following the height of two inside divs, but it didn't work because the two inside divs have `float:left` style.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;` and `height: 100%;`. Post some code if you want better help.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you try to clarify? Your question doesn't make much sense at all. Check your question for typos and show us what code you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, I think you need your parent div contains both 2 dynamic size children. You can set the property `overflow` of the parent to achieve that effect.

```
.parent{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for clearing floats,

Here is the popular clearfix class. Add this CSS

```
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after 
{
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after 
{
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix 
 {
  zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
 }
```

and give your parent div the class

```
class="clearfix"
```

I have read about it
[here](http://www.sitepoint.com/clearing-floats-overview-different-clearfix-methods).

Comment: He/she said this: `I want to arrange two divs horizontally inside a div` - so I don't think that's what he/she meant.

Comment: He succeeded in doing that. But the height of the parent div was not changing dynamically with the height of the children.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}
div{
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid red;
}
.outer{
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 100vh;
}
.inner{
float: left;
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">inner 1
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and t</p>
</div>
<div class="inner">inner 2
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1</p>
</div>
</div>
```